# I want to switch power for a led strip

Tags: power, led

I'm making an on call sign that can be activated via a web page.

I'm not sure if this is even necessary. but i was thinking about using a relay or some other device to power up the strip when in use and not when not in use.

1. is it worth it or should setting the rgb to 0 keep the power usage low?
2. relays seem to be able to switch large signals 110v 10A but i only need 5v 1A(30 rgb leds+30ws2801) can this be done with a different component like transistors or optocouple?
3. i'm using a 5v relay now but haven't been able to get the transistor to send enough to get it to trip.

Thank you.

Comment: A 110v 10A relay will work fine for your application, as long as the power source you use does not blow the LED strip

Answer (score 2):

The ws2801 will indeed still use power, even when all leds are set to zero.

Relay is the safest as it isolates the power of the led-strip from the pi.

You'd need a very beefy transistor to switch 1A of (max-)current. Transistors also have a voltage drop, so the WS2801 will get a lower voltage. Not sure if it likes that. (Sidenote: If the transitor has a voltage drop of 0.6V; then if 1A of current is passing through, the transistor will convert 0.6W of power into heat. Which will make it quite hot without any heatsink)

A better alternative to transistors, in this case, would be to use a MOSFET.

You could use a optocoupler to switch the GATE of the MOSFET. But it quite safe without.

PS did you remember add a (flyback) diode to the relay?

Comment: Yes i have a led in place so i can see it dissipate. thank you.

Comment: Cool effect. Didn't you could use a led for that.